# Unable to install pgcrypto

Tags: postgresql, encryption, centos, pgcrypto

I'm new to postgres, I need to download and install pgcrypto extension. I ran below command but nothing happened:

```
    [root@localhost /]# yum install pgcrypto
   Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.nbrc.ac.in
* extras: mirrors.nhanhoa.com
 * updates: mirror.nbrc.ac.in
No package pgcrypto available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Then, I looked to several of commands on google and tried with below:

```
    [root@localhost ~]# gppkg -r pgcrypto
-bash: gppkg: command not found
```

I'm using postgres 11.3 on centos. Please let me know appropriate command/link from where I can download/install pgcrypto. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for the `postgresql11-contrib` package to install:

```
# yum info postgresql11-contrib
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.triple-it.nl
 * extras: mirror.nforce.com
 * updates: centos.mirror.triple-it.nl
Available Packages
Name        : postgresql11-contrib
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 11.4
Release     : 1PGDG.rhel7
Size        : 617 k
Repo        : pgdg11/7/x86_64
Summary     : Contributed source and binaries distributed with PostgreSQL
URL         : https://www.postgresql.org/
License     : PostgreSQL
Description : The postgresql11-contrib package contains various extension modules that are
            : included in the PostgreSQL distribution.
```

Comment: wow..that's really working. You fixed my problem. Thanks a lot @feike